# How can I type a Redux thunk action creator to return a promise

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, redux-thunk

I have a main thunk that gets executed when clicking a button. Inside this thunk I want to call another thunk and wait for it to complete before moving forward. The second thunk returns a promise.

Here is some of my code:

```
export function mainThunk(): ThunkAction<void, void, void, AnyAction> {
    return (dispatch: Dispatch<any>) => {
    ...do some stuff
    dispatch(secondThunk()).then(() => {
     ...do other stuff
     })
    };
}

export function secondThunk(): ThunkAction<Promise<any>, void, void, AnyAction> {
    return (dispatch: Dispatch<any>) => {
      return new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
        someAsyncFunction()
        .then((response) => {
           return Promise.all(someArray.map(someId => {
             return someOtherAsyncFunction(someId):
         }));
        })
        .then((responses) => {
           response.foreach(response => {
             dispatch(someReduxAction(response.someField));
           });
        })
        .then(() => {
          resolve();
        });
    });
    };
}
```

The code seems to work during execution, but I have a compilation error saying: `Property "then" does not exist on type "ThunkAction<Promise<any>, void, void, AnyAction>"`

I have been reading through other stack overflow posts but I can't seem to find what I'm I missing here that I can't get typescript to think its correct.

Comment: Your code is very convoluted. Specifically, `.then(() => {
          resolve();
        });`, illustrates a fundamental misunderstanding of promises. You also have over specified the types of various elements.

Comment: Why is `.then(() => { resolve(); });` a problem? How else would I tell the promise when to resolve then?

Comment: You shouldn't be creating a promise in the first place because you already have one. That's the misunderstanding.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the solution. 
Once you use the thunk middleware, your dispatch becomes a `ThunkDispatch` instead of a plain `Dispatch`. But Typescript is smart, you actually don't have to type the dispatch function. So removing the type on dispatch fixes the issue. See below:

```
export function mainThunk(): ThunkAction<void, void, void, AnyAction> {
    return (dispatch) => {
    ...do some stuff
    dispatch(secondThunk()).then(() => {
     ...do other stuff
     })
    };
}

export function secondThunk(): ThunkAction<Promise<any>, void, void, AnyAction> {
    return (dispatch) => {
      return new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
        someAsyncFunction()
        .then((response) => {
           return Promise.all(someArray.map(someId => {
             return someOtherAsyncFunction(someId):
         }));
        })
        .then((responses) => {
           response.foreach(response => {
             dispatch(someReduxAction(response.someField));
           });
        })
        .then(() => {
          resolve();
        });
    });
    };
}
```